# How to asynchronously fetch data from multiple sources?

Tags: c#, xaml, asynchronous, windows-8

I am developing a windows 8 application using C# and XAML where I have a huge number of data that I am fetching in a single page. Consequently, the app is taking to much time to load since it needs to wait until all data is present then display them for the users.

What i want mainly is the following: my Gridview has up to 15 groups in it and each group has around 10 tiles. Currently I need to wait till all the data loads then display all groups which is taking to much time since each group has in addition to its tiles some RSS Feeds to Fetch and parse as well. So is there a way to show the groups progressively in a way that when group1 finishes loading it shows then group2 is added, ect...\
Hope the question is clearer now.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This quenstion is so vague, but the basics say it that, you have to use some kind of brackground worker with a callback that lets you know when the work is ready, or in this case when the data has been fetched from the source. You could use threads for that, but maybe that will be a bit more complex.

Have a look here:

http://elegantcode.com/2009/07/03/wpf-multithreading-using-the-backgroundworker-and-reporting-the-progress-to-the-ui/

You can also use the new async/await keywords which makes it extremmally easy:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx

So say you have a couple of background work processes going on, you can then check after each one completes, using some counter, to check if all background processes finished and update the user interface accordling.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Tasks to fetch the data off of the UI thread and update the UI using a dispatcher as the data comes in.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/dd537609.aspx

Tasks are simple to create and use.

```
 var task = new Task(() => Console.WriteLine("Running a task."));
 task.Start();
```